# Difference between dirichlet regression and dirichlet multinomial regression?

Tags: regression, multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

Is there a difference between dirichlet regression and dirichlet multinomial regression? Or are they terminology for the same regression model?

I understand that in DR, one is regressing on the $\alpha_i$ on some covariates, so that one use a linear regression method on a non-exponential distribution.  What about the dirichlet multinomial regression?